# Set image for disabled button in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, imagebutton

I'm using the below **ControlTemplate** for image button in my application.

Control Template in **App.xaml** is below.

```
<!--Below is the style for all ImageButtons in this project -->
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleIB" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </Grid.Projection>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" />
                                        <!--d:IsOptimized="True"-->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.CenterOfRotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" />
                                        <!--d:IsOptimized="True"-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now in my page i'm creating the button as below.

```
  <Button x:Name="saveButton" Style ="{StaticResource ButtonStyleIB}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="save_button_clicked">
            <Image Source="/STCDirectory;component/Images/save.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Button>
```

Upto this it is fine. So when i run the application the button with image is displaying.
And it is working fine.

Now based on some internal condition i want to disable the image button.
So for disable the button i'm using the below code.

```
saveButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

So then image button is not clickable according to the above step.

**But i want to change the image also whenever the button is disabled.**

How could i achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont give direct uri of the image in the buttons 
you can bind it with a string property and on button click you can change the that string to another uri then it will change the image of the button to new image.

i hope this might help ...

Comment: I'm new to windows phone development, Could you pleas explain in detail.

Comment: are you using ViewModel ??

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using imagesource binding ..first define your button like this.

```
  <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="saveButton" Style ="{StaticResource ButtonStyleIB}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="saveButton_Click_1" Width="300" Height="50">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Button>
```

and in your page.xaml.cs create property ImageSource like this.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageSource = "/Assets/1.jpg";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private string _ImageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImageSource = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void saveButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSource = "/Assets/2.jpg";
        saveButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }


}
```

here 1.jpg and 2.jpg are images i have toggled.